# running exe command from another directory in a for loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, command

grep.exe has to be in the current directory in order for the below command to work:

```
FOR /F tokens^=4^ delims^=^" %%A IN ('grep.exe -o -P -m 1 "name=\"securitytoken\" value=\".*?\"" "forum_post_edit.html"') DO SET "securitytoken=%%A"
ECHO %securitytoken%
```

I tried enclosing the path to grep.exe between double quotes like "bin/grep.exe" but that messed up the syntax of the code.

Now I can use pushd and popd to temporarily switch to another directory where grep.exe is located but that affects forum_post_edit.html

How can I work around this problem?

Comment: The easiest solution would be using short 8.3 path to grep.exe as this would not require double quotes around grep.exe with path because no space in path.

Answer (score 2):

Building on @Mofi's comment above, you can extract the short name of `grep.exe` using this command:

```
FOR /F %%A IN ("grep.exe") DO SET GrepPath=%%~fs$PATH:A
```

Now you can reference the short path in your command:

```
FOR /F tokens^=4^ delims^=^" %%A IN ('%GrepPath% -o -P -m 1 "name=\"securitytoken\" value=\".*?\"" "forum_post_edit.html"') DO SET "securitytoken=%%A"
ECHO %securitytoken%
```

**Note**: `grep.exe` would need to be in a folder defined in your system `%PATH%` directory in order for this to work.